# How to set Ogone Ingenico after payment back urls?

Tags: orders, cart, payment, redirect, plugin

I've an existing Magento ecommerce and I've to manage some operations in the final part of the payment process, exactly in the script redirected after the payment done through the Ogone Ingenico plugin.

At the moment in the redirection settings of Ogono Ingenico I set these default links for Magento back redirections

[image]

```
http://[MY_ECOMMERCE_WEBSITE]/ops/api/postBack
```

But once the payment is done, I've been redirected to a url that looks like this ..

```
http://[MY_ECOMMERCE_WEBSITE]/checkout/cart/
```

.. and Magento actually shows a page of an empty shopping cart. I would expect instead a thank-you page in a correct scenario, or an error-payment page in an unsuccessful scenario.

Am I doing something wrong? Do you have suggestions for me to understand other configurations that I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you contact the extension support?

Comment: Well, no, but according to this interesting [article about payment](http://www.nr-apps.com/faq/content/41/216/en/why-are-the-payment_statuses-different-in-magento-and-the-payment-provider-backend.html), my check of the payment-back urls is correct. So I assume that the extension support is not needed. What I need to know first of all is if this `http://[MY_ECOMMERCE_WEBSITE]/checkout/cart/` where I'm redirected (apparently from here `http://[MY_ECOMMERCE_WEBSITE]/ops/api/postBack`) at the end of the payment process is correct or not.

Comment: Make sure you check : ' I would like to receive transaction feedback parameters on the redirection URLs.' in Ogone interface. This way Magento 2 plugin will received orderId and can process correctly the checkout success.

Answer (score 1):

The configured feedback URLs are correct. From the Ingenico webservice you will get redirected to `http://[MY_ECOMMERCE_WEBSITE]/ops/api/postBack` where status information appended to the request will get validated and processed.

Depending on the result and status information you will be then redirected to either one of `http://[MY_ECOMMERCE_WEBSITE]/ops/payment/[accept|exception|decline|cancel]`, where your checkout session will get updated with the last successful ids etc.

From there you should either reach the checkout/success page or a refilled shopping cart in case the payment got canceled or something went wrong. Your case suggests, that the extension was not able to refill the shopping cart.

I would suggest having a look at the exception.log and the ops.log for corresponding errors. Also I really recommend contacting the extension support (ingenico.support@nr-apps.com) as it's free and the guys will most likely be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The return URLs are passed to Ogone in the request done during checkout. You can see how the return URLs are formed in `app/code/community/Netresearch/OPS/Model/Config.php`, but, in a nutshell they are something like `{{base_url}}/ops/payment/$ACTION` where action can be accept, decline, cancel etc.

In Ogone interface you're configuring the endpoint for the server-to-server calls, basically for the Magento endpoint that Ogone posts back when you're performing operations in Ogone interface, like canceling a payment, or capturing an authorization etc.

Going back to your issue, enable Ogone's debug mode from the admin, System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Services -> Ogone Account -> Debug set to Yes, the watch the logs for requests and responses. Check for NCERROR and NCERRORPLUS fields in Ogone's responses and look up what the errors mean in their documentation. One piece or warning though, when debug mode is enabled, Ogone credentials used by Magento are included in the logs.

Cheers

Comment: One of the logs says `Warning: include(Netresearch/OPS/Helper/Api.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /www/[PROJECT]/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94` . I tried event to install again the plugin _The Official Ingenico (former Ogone) Extension_ but I got this error **CONNECT ERROR: Package 'Ogone' is invalid
'./skin/frontend/base/default/css/ops.css' already exists** but the extension is not in the list of the packages.